# Label added to Ionic app shows in web browser preview but not on app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

So i created an app by following a tutorial on YouTube and in the web browser at the top left it says 'rest duration' and at the left is a selectable datetime function. These are both visable in the web browser but not on the application on my mobile device.

I have tried changing ion-label color and nothing changes. The function of the datetime is there as i know where to press but cannot see the actual text.

Also in the time picker, no other numbers are visable only the number that it is on to select.

See image.

below is the code where the teacher changed the label so it was visable but it does not work for.

```html
<ion-content>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="primary"> Rest Duration</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime #myPicker display-format="mm:ss" placeholder="Tap here" [(ngModel)]="fullTime"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
```

[web browser app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDH8J.jpg) This is what the app is showing in the browser (at the top you can see what i want to show)

[mobile application screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ1ub.jpg) and this what is displayed on the mobile application.

Below is the homepage.html code

```
<ion-content>

<ion-item>
    <ion-label color="warning"> Rest Duration</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime #myPicker display-format="mm:ss" placeholder="Tap here" [(ngModel)]="fullTime"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>

<div style="height:50%"> 
<circle-progress (click)="startTime()"
  [percent]="percent"
  [maxPercent]="100"
  [radius]="radius"
  [showTitle]="false"  
  [showSubtitle]="false"
  [showUnits]="false"
  [outerStrokeWidth]="16"
  [outerStrokeColor]="'#8000FF'"
  [showZeroOuterStroke]="false"
  [backgroundStroke]="'#33003F'"
  [backgroundStrokeWidth]="3"
  [outerStrokeGradient]="true"
  [outerStrokeGradientStopColor]="'#FF00CB'"
  [showInnerStroke]="false"
```

> 

```
<p>{{ elapsed.h }} : {{ elapsed.m }} : {{ elapsed.s }}</p>

<ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
    <ng-container *ngIf="timer == false; else running">
        <ion-fab-button (click)="startTime()">
            <ion-icon name="play"></ion-icon>
        </ion-fab-button>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #running>
        <ion-fab-button (click)="stopTime()">
            <ion-icon name="square"></ion-icon>
        </ion-fab-button>
    </ng-template>
</ion-fab>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ion-content>
        <ion-item>
          <p> Rest Duration</p>
            <ion-datetime #myPicker display-format="mm:ss" placeholder="Tap here" [(ngModel)]="fullTime"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, this makes the rest duration huge on the web browser but still not appearing on the app screen on my mobile device

Comment: i have updated, and added screenshots from web preview vs mobile app

Comment: ion-datetime {
                                border: 1px solid rgba(213, 213, 213, 1);
                                border-radius: 30px;
                                border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
                                min-width: 100%;
                                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                                background-size: 20px;
                                background-position: right 15px top 15px;
                            }

Comment: Add this style sheet . It may help you

Comment: Hi Kevin, I tried adding this style sheet but still doesn't appear on my mobile app

Comment: i have added the full homepage.html code snippet that is being used